# JSON string containing regular expression as data

Tags: jsonp, getjson, json

I am reading JSON code from the database and then parsing the string using json parsers available for java. But I am getting JSONexception. Even if I try to parse this string on an online parser http://json.parser.online.fr/ there also the strings are taken as errors. Is there a way out to get rid of these errors or in other words how can I take care of such special symbols. The value of match is a regular expression.

Here is subpart of the sample string I am trying to parse as a json object.

```
 {"RULE":[{"replace":{"value":"","type":"text"},"match":{"value":"<a [^>]*><img   src="[^"]*WindowsLiveWriter/IconsfordifferentSocialBookmarkingSites[^>]*>\s*</a>","type":"text"}},{"replace":{"value":"","type":"text"},"match":{"value":"<a [^>]*><img src="[^"]*WindowsLiveWriter/IconsfordifferentSocialBookmarkingSites[^>]*>\s*</a>","type":"text"}}]}
```

Comment: how did this JSON was generated, isn't it malformed?

Comment: Thanks. Actually I haven't created my own json. This is what I am getting from a website which exchange its data using json. The error I am getting from http://json.parser.online.fr/ is "comma is missing" in this part--- [^"]*WindowsLiveWriter/IconsfordifferentSocialBookmarkingSites[^>]*>\s*</a>","type":"text"

Comment: You can already see here `src="[^"]*Windows...` that the `"` inside `[^"]` must be escaped. And `\s` is not a valid character escape sequence in JSON, it must be encoded as `\\s` if you want `\s` literally.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. Actually I tried escaping the characters as you suggested i.e for " and \s but still I am getting the same parsing error that comma is missing. I am just parsing it on json.parser.online.fr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this json

`{"RULE":[{"replace":{"value":"","type":"text"},"match":{"value":"<a [^>]*><img   src=\"[^\"]*WindowsLiveWriter/IconsfordifferentSocialBookmarkingSites[^>]*>\\s*</a>","type":"text"}},{"replace":{"value":"","type":"text"},"match":{"value":"<a [^>]*><img src=\"[^\"]*WindowsLiveWriter/IconsfordifferentSocialBookmarkingSites[^>]*>\\s*</a>","type":"text"}}]}`